# How to send float values from Arduino-UNO to ESP8266-01

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to send data from `arduino`to `esp-01` but i am only able to send integer values or If i am sending floating values it is received as integer by `esp-01` through software serial

I tried sending with software serial, also tried typecasting float to string but it was giving me error while passing string to `myserial.write(STRING)`

```
data = 0.00005146;
myserial.write(data);
```

Comment: please click 'improve' instead of 'reject and edit' if you use most of my changes while editing your post.

Comment: Pls post entire code

Answer (score 0):

Use Serial.println() function from the sending end

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  float x = 0.00005146;
  Serial.println(x, 8);
  delay(1000);
}
```

On the other end use the following

```
float x;
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String Data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    x = Data.toFloat();
    Serial.println(x, 8)
}
```

Note: floats have only 6-7 decimal digits of precision and that longer Strings might be truncated.